# P[Node].rep produces P[String] rather than array of nodes

Tags: fastparse

I would expect the result for plusses to be some kind of array

```
case class Plus()
val plus: P[Plus] = P ("+") map {_ => Plus()}
val plusses: P[List[Plus]] = P ( plus.rep.! )  // type mismatch; found: Parser[String]  required: Parser[List[Plus]]
```

but compiler says

> type mismatch;  found   : Parser[String]  required: Parser[List[Plus]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

First, you don't need to capture something with `.!` as you already have a result in the `plus` parser. The `.rep` then "creates" a parser that repeats the `plus` parser 0 to n times and concatenates the result into a `Seq[Plus]`.

```
case class Plus()
val plus: P[Plus] = P ("+") map {_ ⇒ Plus()}
val plusses: P[Seq[Plus]] = P ( plus.rep )
```

Second, if using the repeat operation `rep`, `Parser`s return `Seq` and not `List`  If you really need a list, use map to convert `Seq` to `List`.

```
val plussesAsList: P[List[Plus]] = P( plus.rep ).map( seq ⇒ seq.toList)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.!` is "to capture the section of the input string the parser parsed" (see http://lihaoyi.github.io/fastparse/#Capture). So the return type of `.!` is `String`.

I think what you want is:

```
val plusses: P[List[Plus]] = P ( plus.rep ) map (_.toList)
```

Here's what you will get:

```
@ plusses.parse("+++")
res6: core.Result[List[Plus]] = Success(List(Plus(), Plus(), Plus()),3)
```